# Background Fetch and Local Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, uilocalnotification, background-fetch

In my app, I am planning to use Local Notification and not Push Notifications. I need to check whether a transaction update is available, if YES, just notify the user with Local Notification. I have done the below steps.

1. In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, set fetch interval `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum]`.
2. `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {`

> Added code for POST Request as below with my request data:

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(conn) {
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
 else {
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
}
```

3. After response parsing, comparing if any update is there and if any update is there, notification is displayed using the below code.

   ```
   UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
   localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
   localNotification.alertTitle = @&quot;SIB Mirror&quot;;
   localNotification.alertBody = @&quot;You have a new transaction. Go to e-Statements to view it.&quot;;
   localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
   ```

The issue is most of the times, when phone is locked, getting error message 
>Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."

and hence notification was not getting displayed. But when I connect Phone directly to Phone and in debug mode enable background sync, every thing works properly.

Kindly guide me an easy approach to do this or correct me if anything I am doing wrongly.

Thanks,

Mobile Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
            NSError * error = nil;
            NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                  returningResponse:&response
                                                              error:&error];

if (error == nil)
{
 // Parse data here
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
else {
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);

}
```

Comment: Please note that background task won't work if the app is killed by the user. You need push notification to implement your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

This part of your code

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(conn) {
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
else {
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
}
```

Is saying, create me a connection to get some data, and no matter what happens with the creation of this instance complete the background processing. So iOS does as you ask and stops the app.

If the connection can't be created then complete with failed, sure. But if the connection was created you shouldn't be calling completion until you have a response (data or error) to process...

Comment: How to check what? You already check the connection you just do the wrong thing as a result. And you need to save the completion handler so you can use it in the connection delegate callbacks...

Answer (score 0):

> Try POST Request with completion handler.